# Nvidia Control Panel No option for GPU scaling in the drop down menu

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, scaling

Here are my PC specs:

- CPU: Intel Core i3 2100 @3.1GHz
- GPU: Gigabyte GTX 750 Ti
- RAM: 8GB
- Mobo: Gigabyte GA-H61M-S2P (rev 2.0)
- Monitor: Samsung SyncMaster 740n (1024x768) VGA

A few days ago I had the same PC but with a GeForce 210 and I could play games at 16:9 resolution while forcing a letterbox. Now I upgraded to the GTX 750 Ti and when I try to play games at a 16:9 resolution the game gets stretched and sometimes parts of it are not appearing on the screen.

As you can see in the picture the only option I get is `display` and my screen is old, so it doesn't have scaling options:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/IBXYypo.png]

Forgot to say. Since the GTX 750 Ti doesn't have a VGA connector I had to buy a converter (DVI-I to VGA) for my monitor to work on it (I don't know if this helps)

Please help

Comment: To do scaling on the graphics card shouldn't `Aspect Ratio` radio button above be selected then you should have appropriate options to choose from?

Comment: @albal Thanks for replying. I tried choosing Aspect ratio scaling mode and apply but I still get 1 option for scaling which is display

Comment: bump :/ any help?